# Json Decode to swift class with dynamic value class/struct type

Tags: ios, json, swift, generics, codable

I have multiple responses which has similar pattern but one key value has always different object in response of json which i want to decode in base model where one key has variety of object type.

Response be like,

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Success",
"data":[]
}
```

Here in `data` response it has any kind of array of objects or any single object

```
struct BaseResponseModel: Codable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String
    var data: DataClass
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message
        case data
        case status
    }
}
```

what we can do here to make it single class with data type object pass,

Anyone please..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Swift `generics`, and provide the type only at the time of decoding:

```
struct BaseResponseModel<DataType: Codable>: Codable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String
    var data: DataType
}
```

Usage:

```
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseResponseModel<MyStruct>.self, from: data).data // For object
let myData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseResponseModel<[MyStruct]>.self, from: data).data // For array
```

Note: You don't need `CodingKeys` if the rawValues are the same.

Comment: DataType is not always single object, it may be array of objects, How it work?

Comment: Added usage example for object and array.